# How to debug web sites on mobile devices when using host file?

Tags: debugging, mobile, remote-debugging, web-inspector

I am running my website from my windows PC: I have changed hosts file and now I am using

> 127.0.0.1 mywebsite.com

My problem is: How can I now debug it on my mobilePhone ?

1) chrome phone emulation is not good enough: I need it to see it on real device.

2) chrome://inspect/#devices : will not me open mywebsite.com since it is linked to my local PC

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Where is the site running, on your mobile?

Comment: Site is running on my local PC

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Apache, here are some high-level steps:

- Figure out your PC's IP adres. Preferably configure your router to always give that IP to that PC. Take note (probably something like 192.168.1.100)
- Check what port Apache is listening on. Take note (default should be 80)
- Configure Apache to allow remote connections. There are some rules, or at least one, saying `require local` which should be changed to `required all granted`. Be wary that this allows external devices to access (parts of) your filesystem. Think twice, grant access once.
- Connect your phone to the same network your PC is in. surf to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyyy where the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is your PC's IP adres, and the yyyyy is the port number you wrote down earlier. this is a value below 65536. All numbers should be equal in length or shorter then the placeholders provided.

For more info on any one of these steps, please update your question or create a new one, depending on which would be more relevant.